# Lubuntu 20.04 hibernate button activation

Tags: lubuntu, hibernate, button

I'm using Lubuntu 20.04 and I can hibernate my system using terminal with `sudo systemctl hibernate` command. But when I click the hibernate button from `leave` menu, I just get a warning error that say's `Do you want to really hibernate your computer?` and after accepting, nothing happens !!!

Comment: check the output of the `dmesg` command after this event, you may see the reason there...

Comment: `dmesg` shows nothing. only my last activities like opening libreoffice and ...

Comment: How much memory do you have and how large is your swap file?

Comment: 4G RAM and 2G swap

Comment: I use Lubuntu 20.04

Comment: You need to have enough unused swap to write all your RAM to it... ie. if you're using 1GB of swap at the time you ask for hibernation; you'll need 5GB (4GB of RAM to be written to it + the 1GB already used...)

Comment: my used swap is almost every time 0GB when system is working. I have partition swap no swap file. Should I extend its capasity or do some thing more?

Comment: If you have a swap partition you will need a live environment to resize it. First step would be to reduce the size of an adjacent partition, then increase the swap partition. Alternatively switch to a swap file.

Comment: increasing swap size will let hibernate burron to work? I said that hibernating with command is working but hibernate button not working

Comment: Conventional wisdom is as per @guiverc comment. However this appears not to be the case as per this answer. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1124315/two-swapfiles-hibernate-working-how-to-correctly-configure-hibernate-to-not-ru?rq=1

Comment: From what you report it would seem the hibernate button does not do the same thing as the command line method. Perhaps that method does need more swap space. You could test that by creating a swap file, turning off the swap partition and turning on the swap file

Comment: can I extend swap partition and test it ?

Comment: Yes, I assumed that would be more complicated. If you do any partition operations make sure you have backups of any data you cannot afford to lose